# python requests return javascript

Tags: python, python-requests

I'm trying to get the HTML data from "https://edition.cnn.com", but for some reason I'm getting JavaScript(?) instead. I tried using Python's `requests` and `urllib` modules, both with and without `User-Agent`.

This is my code:

```
html = urllib.request.urlopen("https://edition.cnn.com")
print(html.read())
```

or:

```
raw_web_data = requests.get("https://edition.cnn.com")
```

and this is part of the response I'm getting:
when i'm trying to save the full response as html it wont show me a valid webpage, more like someking of text file. and a lot of classes are missing

```
.cd.cd--vertical .cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical [data-eq-state$=medium].cd.cd--vertical .cd__headline a{font-size:26px;line-height:36px}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__kicker{padding-left:1rem;padding-right:1rem}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd--small.cd--vertical .cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd.cd--small.cd--vertical .cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd.cd--small.cd--vertical .cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd.cd--small.cd--vertical .cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd.cd--small.cd--vertical .cd__headline a{padding:1rem 1rem 0}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.link-banner,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.link-banner,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.link-banner,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.link-banner,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.link-banner{padding:36px 1rem 0}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before{background:#fefefe;border:8px solid #fefefe;bottom:-8px;font-size:30px;left:0;margin:0 auto;position:absolute;right:0;width:30px}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__status{bottom:auto;left:50%;margin:0 auto;text-align:center;-webkit-transform:translateX(-50%);-ms-transform:translateX(-50%);transform:translateX(-50%);white-space:nowrap}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd.cd .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd.cd .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd.cd .cd__status,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd.cd .cd__status{top:0}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__headline,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__headline,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__headline,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__headline,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__kicker,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__description,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__headline,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__kicker{text-align:center}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__headline-icon:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__headline-icon:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__headline-icon:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__headline-icon:before,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__headline-icon:before{content:""}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-1x1 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical-3x4 .cd__auxiliary,.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-vertical .cd__auxiliary{line-height:20px}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd--video .cd__headline-text:before{content:"\xef\x85\x87";font-family:cnn-icons}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-vertical .cd--gallery .cd__headline-text:before{content:"\xef\x85\x84";font-family:cnn-icons}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-no-leading-headline .cd.cd--vertical.cd--idx-0[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-no-leading-headline .cd.cd--vertical.cd--idx-0[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-no-leading-headline .cd.cd--vertical.cd--idx-0[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content{margin-top:0}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-no-leading-headline .cd--idx-0 .cd__kicker{margin-bottom:0}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__headline{background-color:#fefefe;width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__headline{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd.cd--vertical[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-xs li+li .banner-text{padding-top:1rem}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-horizontal .cd__status{display:inline-block;margin-bottom:8px;position:static}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__status{position:absolute}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-horizontal .cd__description{display:none}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-large-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__description{display:block}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-small-horizontal .cd__status{display:none}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .link-banner,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__content .link-banner{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__headline{background-color:#fefefe;width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__headline{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__headline{background-color:#fefefe;width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__headline{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__headline{background-color:#fefefe;width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__headline{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-xs .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-piped .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 24px)!important}.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-list-hierarchical-small-horizontal .cd[data-eq-state~=full16x9] .cd__description{width:calc(100% - 48px)!important}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd.cd.cd .cd__headline-text{font-family:CNN Condensed,CNN,Helvetica Neue,Helvetica,Arial,Utkal,sans-serif;-webkit-font-feature-settings:"kern";font-feature-settings:"kern";text-rendering:optimizeLegibility}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small[data-eq-state~="2-column-grid"] .cd.cd .cd__headline a{font-weight:400;font-size:14px;line-height:1.43;padding-top:8px}@media (min-width:480px){.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small[data-eq-state~="2-column-grid"] .cd.cd .cd__headline a{font-size:16px;line-height:1.5}}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small[data-eq-state~="3-column-grid"] .cd.cd .cd__headline a{font-size:18px;line-height:24px;padding-top:12px}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small[data-eq-state~="4-column-grid"] .cd.cd .cd__headline a{font-size:20px;line-height:1.4}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd--tool__feed .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .link-banner:hover+.cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .media:hover+.cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon){-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -3px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -4px 0 #d9d9d9;box-shadow:inset 0 -3px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -4px 0 #d9d9d9}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .link-banner:hover+.cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .media:hover+.cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon){-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -5px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -6px 0 #d9d9d9;box-shadow:inset 0 -5px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -6px 0 #d9d9d9}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd--tool__feed .media:hover+.cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd__content .cd__headline a:hover span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .link-banner:hover+.cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .link-banner:hover+.cd__wrapper .cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon),.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .media:hover+.cd__content .cd__headline a span:not(.cd__headline-icon){-webkit-box-shadow:inset 0 -7px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -8px 0 #d9d9d9;box-shadow:inset 0 -7px 0 #fefefe,inset 0 -8px 0 #d9d9d9}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd.cd--vertical .cd__kicker+.cd__headline a{padding-top:36px}.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-grid-small .cd.cd .cd__post-headline{padding-bottom:1px}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd__content{margin:-28px 10px 0;padding:0 0 2rem;position:relative!important;width:calc(100% - 20px);z-index:1}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd.cd.cd--has-media[data-eq-state~=medium] .media+.cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd.cd.cd--has-media[data-eq-state~=medium] .cd--tool__feed .media+.cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd.cd.cd--has-media[data-eq-state~=medium] .media+.cd__content{position:static!important}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd--tool__feed .cd-feed__content,.pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd[data-eq-state~=large] .cd__content{bottom:auto;left:auto;margin:auto;padding:2rem 0;right:80px;top:50%;-webkit-transform:translateY(-60%);-ms-transform:translateY(-60%);transform:translateY(-60%);width:380px;z-index:1}.cd--tool__feed .pg.pg-vertical.pg-vertical--politics .cn-carousel-small-paginated .cd.cd.cd.cd--has-media[data-eq-state~=large] .media+.cd-
```

Comment: What's the problem?

Comment: That looks like css classes. My guess is you are getting a rendered version of the page as a response.

Comment: Is that the full response? What do you mean by part of the response?

Comment: No this is part of the response, i can't share sthe full response because there are more then 300k of chars, and the limit of stackoverflow is 30k.
but you can try and run the code i wrote, when i'm saving it as html i't wont show me a webpage. more like text file

Comment: What must be happening is that the website must be loading its main content using javascript or better, inside an iframe, that's why you did not get complete html page. `requests` won't help you in dealing with situations like this. `selenium` might do. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55316754/4428377) from below.

Comment: what info did you want from the page?